# isteven-multi-select in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

Can i use isteven-multi-select with ng-model? What i want to do is when the page is opened, some items should be  seem as chosen in isteven-multi-select modul.In html page, maybe i can use ng-model to fill isteven-multi-select items.But i could not do it.Do you have any idea?

```
<div isteven-multi-select input-model="vm.list" ng-model="vm.list.countries"
            output-model="vm.list.countries" button-label="icon name"
            item-label="icon name" tick-property="ticked"
            helper-elements="all,filter,none" output-properties="screenName"
            max-height="300px"></div>
```

Comment: Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You should add extra field `ticked` to objects in vm.list.If you set ticket property as true, it will already be pre-selected